# Colorbox formatter

Tags: 7, javascript

I'm using the colorbox for my site's lightboxes but the formatter don't work to me.

I'm using this function

[theme_colorbox_imagefield($variables)](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!colorbox!colorbox.theme.inc/function/theme_colorbox_imagefield/7)
like this

```
$to_render = array(
            'path' => $item['uri'],
            'style_name' => $display['settings']['image_style']
          );

$big_img_url = image_style_url('original', $to_render['path']); 
$img = theme('colorbox_imagefield', array('image' => $to_render, 'path' => $big_img_url, 'title' => 'title', 'gid' => 'node-gallery'));
```

and the output is

```
<a href="http://www.site.com/sites/default/files/styles/original/public/201208091308330._820px_2_2.jpg?itok=0O22dcFd" title="title" class="colorbox" rel="node-gallery">   
   <img src="http://www.site.com/sites/default/files/styles/tutorial/public/201208091308330._820px_2_2.jpg?itok=BEbh2N_O" alt="">   
</a>
```

but on click it work like a normal link.

What am I missing?

UPDATE:

I tryed to unistall and reinstall the module and display an image field with the colourbox normal display and the result is this:
[image]

I decide to unistall the module and sobstitute it with lightbox2 to implement image lightbox.

Comment: What are your colorbox configuration settings?

Comment: Hi beth, I do not think the problem is in configuration file because I tryed to unistall module, reinstall it and display an image field with the colourbox normal display and the result is bugged. [I added a screenshot in the issues question.. ]

Comment: No one will be able to help you if you don't provide information that people ask about.